# Stack Element Numbers

Tags: c, lua, stack

So, I'm working with the Lua C API and I'm very new to the stack system. I'm learning how to manage stacks and push and pop elements, but I'm a little confused with the numbers.

I know that -1 refers to the top element in the stack and 1 is the first element to be pushed onto the stack.
if 1 is the first element, is the top element 3?
And is -2 and 2 the exactly same thing?

Comment: You are not showing any code. If you are talking about stack algorithm, it's depend on implmentation.

Comment: The answer depends on how many elements have been pushed onto the stack. If there are 3 elements, then yes, the first element has index 1 and also indexed by -3. 2 and -2 are both indices for the middle element. If you push or pop elements, the positive indices stay the same, but the negative ones change.

Answer (score 4):

The first item on the stack is always at 1 and the last element at -1. If there are N elements then the last element can also be referenced at N and the first at -N. As you push elements  onto stack N increases, as you pop elements or use C API functions that pop elements off the stack you decrease N.